# change rest api server from using http to https protocol- c#

Tags: c#, rest, http, https

i have runing server that based on rest api .Net Feamework 4.5.2
that use http protocol, i need to change the server to use https protocol, there is an easy way to do the change?

Comment: All changes need to be made at the IIS level. And you will need a certificate for it.